# FORCE.COM IDE not refreshing project from salesforce

Tags: force.com-ide

Environment:
I have mac with os el capitan, Eclipse Java EE Mars Release 4.5.0 with force.com IDE http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42 updated today.

Problem:

If I create any component e:g vf page directly in salesforce.com then select ide to refresh from server for a salesforce project, it failed to pull new components from salesforce.

Anyone know any solution for this, I have searched previous posts and tried but still struggling to fix this problem.

Regards,

Comment: is your problem is work as online?

Answer (score -1):

You need to select Add/Remove Components.. There you can select recently created your VF page!

Refreshing means it'll refresh only existing components in your IDE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Sorry I missed to mention I am selecting Add/Remove Component.

I think it is more eclipse problem as  it throwing a  NullPointerException when it try to refresh.

Comment: Ended up reinstalling Eclipse and things are seems working :)

Comment: Cheers!! Have a good day..